# Find recently modified files on windows console

Tags: cmd, find, windows-console

I need to check in cmd if there are specific files recently modified (90 min).

On linux, my command works well:

```
find /home/my_folder -type f -mmin -90 -name *.txt
```

On MS-DOS, I cannot find a way to filter regarding modification time:

```
forfiles /P directory /S
```

Comment: windows cmd, maybe it is not the right name (usually I don't use winz). Win7

Comment: Just install [cywgin](http://cygwin.com) - that way you can use familiar *nix commands like `find` on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /C parameter:

/C    command       Indicates the command to execute for each file.
                        Command strings should be wrapped in double
                        quotes.

```
                    The default command is "cmd /c echo @file".

                    The following variables can be used in the
                    command string:
                    @file    - returns the name of the file.
                    @fname   - returns the file name without
                               extension.
                    @ext     - returns only the extension of the
                               file.
                    @path    - returns the full path of the file.
                    @relpath - returns the relative path of the
                               file.
                    @isdir   - returns "TRUE" if a file type is
                               a directory, and "FALSE" for files.
                    @fsize   - returns the size of the file in
                               bytes.
                    @fdate   - returns the last modified date of the
                               file.
                    @ftime   - returns the last modified time of the
                               file.

                    To include special characters in the command
                    line, use the hexadecimal code for the character
                    in 0xHH format (ex. 0x09 for tab). Internal
                    CMD.exe commands should be preceded with
                    "cmd /c".

Ex:- forfiles /S /M *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @path @file @fdate @ftime"
```

Think this might be helpful. You can use **forfiles /?** to see more help details.